# Periodically losing access to internal hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

Periodically losing access to an internal 2 TB hard disk drive, already reseated the cables and applyed a 12h long chkdsk, with no identified errors. I typically regain access upon reboot, and then loose it a few hours into computer usage. I am booting from an SSD.

Message looks like this: "F:/ is not accessible." Drive is still visible on Windows Explorer even while unacessible, and also shows up on Disk Management. Some folders also remain accessible, while others either don't or register as empty, even though they still occupy space as seen on the drive's properties.

- OS: Windows 10
- Processor: Intel Core i5 11600K (Issue appeared after upgrading)
- Motherboard: Asus Prime B560M-A (Issue appeared after upgrading)
- Boot Storage: SSD NVME Kingstom NV1 500 GB (Issue appeared after upgrading)
- Additional Storage: Seagate Barracuda LP 2 TB (Disk "F")
- PSU: Knup-522 500W (Been told it is a subpar PSU, only one 4-pin connector, while the CPU demands an 8-pin one)

Culprit?

SMART details of the disk:

[image: SMART details of the disk]

Comment: I had this some time back and suspected a faulty drive. After replacing the disk everything worked as expected.